# SQL: Setting the "like" condition programmatically

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a list of MerchantNames like so, stored in the Merchant table:

```
MerchantName
------------
Al's
Bart's
Mo's Cafe
```

And I want to do a query like so:

```
select merchantDetail 
from merchant
where merchantDetail like '%' + merchantName + '%'
```

I already tried the above but (as i suspected) it complained about an error in MySQL syntax. I want to do this for every merchant Name in the column. Is something like this possible? Thank you very much.

Comment: For every name? Removing where won't help?

Comment: And what was the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax for the `WHERE` clause in MySQL would be:

```
where merchantDetail like concat('%', merchantName, '%')
```

The `+` is SQL Server syntax for string concatenation.  Note that because you are using `LIKE`, the `'%'` and `'_'` characters have special meanings.  This could affect any merchant names with those characters.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!